# Matplotlib 2.0 log scale masked imshow very different than 1.53

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I recently upgraded from MPL 1.53 to 2.0 and it broke a few of my plots. One in particular that I have not been able to mend is using imshow with log normalization, on a log scale for both x and y with a masked array. I could perhaps use pcolor, pcolormesh, or other but my 2D array is very large (like 20,000 X 20,000 or bigger) and pcolor consumes more than 30GB of RAM to make this plot. I'm attaching 2 pictures generated using the same source code. One was run with matplotlib 2.0.0 and the other was run after uninstalling MPL 2.0.0 and installing MPL 1.53. Can someone help me to figure out why the newer version just won't work?

I have edited the question to include a full working example and the example data does not produce a blank plot with 2.0, but a very different looking one.

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def power_law(x,b):
    return b*(x**0.2)

x=np.logspace(9,16,100)
y=np.logspace(1,3.5,100)
Z=[]
for xi in x:
    zy=[]
    for yi in y:
        if power_law(xi,0.25)<yi and yi <power_law(xi,0.6):
            zy.append(yi*xi)
        else:
            zy.append(np.nan)
    Z.append(zy)
Z=np.array(Z)

Ziv=~np.isnan(Z)
Zval=Z[Ziv]
vmin,vmax=np.amin(Zval),np.amax(Zval)

fig,ax=plt.subplots()
ax.set_xscale('log')
ax.set_yscale('log')
ax.set_ylim(1E9,1E16)
ax.set_ylim(20,2000)

extent=[x[0],x[-1],y[0],y[-1]]
norm=mpl.colors.LogNorm(vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax)
ax.imshow(Z,extent=extent,aspect='auto',origin='lower',cmap='jet',
          vmin=vmin,vmax=vmax,norm=norm)
plt.show()
```

Result using matplotlib 1.53:

[image]

Result using matplotlib 2.0.0:

[image]

Can someone help me figure out what has changed between these two versions and how to get it working again with 2.0?

Comment: See here, [what has changed](http://matplotlib.org/users/whats_new.html#non-linear-scales-on-image-plots). I don't know how this affects your plot, since I don't have `Z`. What happens, if you leave out the `extent` and the axies limits? Would it still not show anything?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue with mpl 2.0.0 using some dummy data for `Z`. Maybe you need to (a) test your code using a simple test data set, or (b) provide us with a minimal, _complete_ example: see [MCVE](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have modified the question with a MCVE. Thank you for your attention. @tom